# Failed Run on a flutter app with error Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm a beginner and recently I just create a flutter project just to test it out am I setup all up correctly and when I run the program this error show-out anyone know how to fix this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     AAPT: error: failed writing to 'C:\Users\A C E R\Desktop\what_name\build\app\intermediates\runtime_symbol_list\debug\R.txt': The data is invalid. (13).



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Run flutter doctor on Terminal/Command Prompt to check that every thing is properly installed or not.

Comment: i run it and no issues found